# How to use custome oauth in meteor+inoic

Tags: meteor

I write a custome oauth module,and add this module to my meteor+ionic project.
I add new method Meteor.loginWithSample,but i can not use this method in my project.
I got

> client/imports/app/app-routing.module.ts (9, 8): Property
>   ‘loginWithSample’ does not exist on type 'typeof Meteor

when compile my project.how can i add my method to @types/meteor.
I used meteor cli
I am a newer for typescript